# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9'

Tags: python, django, json, unicode

i work on ajax's script in views.py of django 1.5. after build my json file, i must put username into cookies. The name have french accent name like 'hervé'. This is a part of my code

```
if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            name = 'Hervé'
            jsondict['success'] = True
            jsondict['text']['welcome'] = 'Bienvenue, %s!' % name

            if name:
                fn = name
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(jsondict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, ensure_ascii=False),mimetype='application/json')
    if fn:
        set_cookie(response,"full_name",fn)
```

error which appear is

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

to solve this i use unicode(), decode()... but nothing change. Is the error came from set_cookie() fonction? or json file? what can i do to solve it?

this is set_cookies function

```
def set_cookie(response, key, value, days_expire = 7):
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
if days_expire is None:
    max_age = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  #one year
else:
    max_age = days_expire * 24 * 60 * 60 
expires = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=max_age), "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
response.set_cookie(key, value, max_age=max_age, expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN, secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None)
```

Comment: `jsondict['text']['welcome'] = u'Bienvenue, %s!' % (user.get_full_name(),)` (notice the u'') ... maybe ? not sure ... It would be more helpful if you used a constant there so we could reproduce it...

Comment: use constant how? like this?    cnst = u'Bienvenue, %s!' % (user.get_full_name(),)
jsondict['text']['welcome'] = cnst

Comment: like `blah = 'some text that has the unicode in it!'`... basically make an example that we can run

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could include the full stack trace rather than just the error message.

Comment: @jogojapan i update the trace http://pastebin.com/hNAjh7jd

Answer (score 1):

OK now I fixed it. In the head of your views.py, put this interpreter

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

Then in your function,

```
name = 'Hervé'
name.decode('latin-1').encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace') //add this line
jsondict['success'] = True
jsondict['text']['welcome'] = 'Bienvenue, %s!' % name
```

Comment: OK I will try to find a solution for this one

Comment: it doesn't work. i think that the error is not in the json file, but in the set_cookies fonction. Or i am wrong?

Comment: I got the same error when I test your original codes. So I put interpreter to interpret the ascii. Maybe you should search more about that. And that codes work on me.

Comment: you are right, your code is working, but i think having an idea why it don't work on me, it is because the name 'hervé' come from the database and i think python encoded like u'hervé' (u'herv\xe9')

Comment: No it's not. I think it will be work, think in other way. I can't give you a fixed solution because I don't know about your project

Comment: i will try to explain it to you, first when i create an user in django administration, django-admin  encode my name 'hervé'. with your explication i have understood that python encode my name as u'Hervé' not 'Hervé'. I am tryint to fix it since hours. if i find the solution with name=u'Hervé' i will find the solution. thank you for all

Comment: ok I will try to input your name in the database and lets see what happen

Comment: it's working on me, I really don't know why you got that error